# What symbol do the images represent?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, computer-puzzle

These are two images representing the same symbol, the first image contains 25 blocks in 13 colors, it represents progression of its different states through time since it was initiated n years ago (`round(n/100, 1) == 0.8`);

The second image shows the intended ordering of the colors. It is not a rainbow and not in sync with the sRGB spectrum.

Can you guess what it is?

[image]

[image]

Hints:

The ***HEXADECIMAL*** values of the colors are very important.

> There is no red (#ff0000) color in the first image, and red has a very specific meaning.

> It goes COUNTER-CLOCKWISE in the second image if you go FORWARD figuratively in time

> 0x3ed9999a # 0.???f

> 0x47a88e00 # ?????.0f

---

The accepted answer must explain both the first image and the second image, and explain what each color in the first image represents.

---

For your convenience, the hexadecimal values for the colors in the first image are:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ffb200 | ff4c00 | ff3300 | ffb200 | ccff00 |
| ffb200 | ffff00 | ccff00 | ffe500 | ffb200 |
| ff6600 | ff4c00 | ff9900 | ffff00 | 4dff00 |
| 99ff00 | ffe500 | ffb200 | ff7f00 | ff9900 |
| ff7f00 | ff4c00 | ff3f00 | ff3300 | ff2a00 |

They correspond to 25 numbers with 13 distinct values.

Comment: this is the strangest version of wordle I've seen yet

Comment: It's not wordle...

Comment: Well, the answers to this question and to the other question I have posted are connected.

Comment: The answer has something to do with Edison, Washington and Batman.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς so we can't solve this until the other is solved?

Comment: Edison, Washington and Batman all have DC. Washington D.C., DC comics, Edison found DC voltage.

Comment: Yep, the above is correct, the answer consists of two simple English words, with initial abbreviation of D.C.

Comment: You've given a *lot* of hints - keep in mind that lots of people only check SE once a day.

Comment: If you're looking for people to confirm that they're doing this, I did notice (all the way back before the first hint) that all the colors were [\_\_/100/100] in HSV, but didn't see where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors represent the

> time remaining on the [Doomsday Clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_Clock) each time it was moved

where the color scale shows

> the angle of the minute hand.